# How do I make it so that when a variable is true in "Form1," it does something in "Form2?"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So, I'm trying to make it so when the user clicks the login button on the login form, it sets a variable to true, then it makes something activate on the main form.
Some pseudo code that would be placed in Form 2:

```
If Form1.button = clicked Then
do something
end if
```

Thanks for any help!

By the way, I'm a complete noob with vb.net. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On button click event write below

```
If Form1.button = clicked Then
  Dim myForm As New Form2
  if LoggedIn = True then
     myForm.UserGroupBox.visible = true
     me.close
     myForm.Show()
  end if

End if
```

Comment: I don't want it to open the form window, I've already done that. I want it to change the property of a groupbox that I have on the main form.

Comment: didnt got what you mean. Please explain more

Comment: I have a simple login form, and when I click the login button, it sets "LoggedIn" to "True" (LoggedIn is a boolean). This all happens in Form1. Now, I want Form2 to recognize that the user is logged in, and I want it to set a groupbox's visible property to True.

Comment: On the Login Button Click sub:
Username = UsernameTextBox.Text
            LoggedIn = True
            MainWindow.UserGroupBox.Visible = True
            MainWindow.UserGroupBox.Enabled = True
            MainWindow.UserGroupBox.Text = Username
            MainWindow.Show()
            Me.Close()
That's it! Your first edit gave me the idea to do this! Thanks!

Comment: have updated answer. hope this is what you need. Accept answer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Double click your Application name in the solution explorer then go to settings and create a new one with the name: clicked    and the value on : 0 and write on the button1 in the form1

```
        Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    My.Settings.clicked = "1"
    form1.show
    me.hide
End Sub
```

and on the form were you want the something

```
if my.settings.clicked = "1" then
'Do Something what you want here
my.settings.clicked = "0"
end if
end sub
```

what this code does is:

when you click then button if gives the my.settings.clickde an value 1 = true

and when the other form loads its gonna check if the value = 1 if the value = 1 then it clicks the button and then changes the clicked value back to 0
so its not gonna repeat forever

hope this helps you and dont forget if it helps click button_up on my post